# Yii2 login issue

Tags: php, yii2

Why is Yii2 authentication such a pain in the ass?

I want to restrict the `index` action of the `SiteController` controller to be accessed by authenticated users only. I have downloaded the basic application template. Here's the code for the `behaviors()` method of `SiteController`:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'index'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

and the `index` action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

The User model is not modified at all. Why when I try to access `site/index`, it correctly redirects me to `site/login` but even after I login with the admin credentials (`admin`/`admin`) I get redirected again to the login page? WTF is wrong here? The funny thing is that I read in the runtime log that the user admin has logged in, but the login page shows up again.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are really logged and your login action work correctly, be sure that you don't have redirection in your urlManager confi or in you htaccess  then you can try also  this way

```
  public function behaviors()
  {
      return [
          'access' => [
              'class' => AccessControl::className(),
              'rules' => [
                  [
                      'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                      'allow' => true,
                  ],
                  [
                      'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                      'allow' => true,
                      'roles' => ['@'],
                  ],
              ],
          ],
          'verbs' => [
              'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
              'actions' => [
                  'logout' => ['post'],
              ],
          ],
      ];
  }
```

Comment: i use this in my app  and work .. are you sure you are correcly logged ?  . and you have not some rediection   urlManager or htacces ?

Comment: If I entered a wrong username and/or password, the login form would display an error, but it does not. As I said, the runtime log logs the successful login, but I get redirected to login again anyway. This is very frustrating...!!!

Comment: It doesn't work even if I add a new action (eg. `mypage`) in the `SiteConroller`.

Comment: you mean actionMypage ?

Comment: Yes, I mean `actionMypage()`.

Comment: Do you have some urlManager and htaccess  configuration ?

Comment: update you question and add  the actionLogin code  ..  please

Comment: Yeah... My bad. I did change something in the `User` model which invalidated the login procedure. I changed the key of the `$users` variable for the admin user, without changing the `id` value of the cell. This caused this erratic behavior. My bad, sorry.